# Angularjs Controller Interestingly Runs Twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background**

I am on a project using angularjs with the following environment specifications:

- Angularjs 1.7.2
- Webpack 4.15.1 - CLI 3.0.1
- @uirouter/angularjs 1.0.18

**The Problem**

I have one of my controllers that runs twice on state change.

**What I did so far?**

I searched and read most of articles about this issue on google. Even I found a nice article [here](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/ed0ce8). It talks about all possible causes of this problem. So I re-checked the followings:

- I do not have any ng-app directive on my html tag nor on my body tag.
- No ng-controller directive on the page that calls the specified controller
- Only one view inside the state uses that controller
- No conflicts with controller names
- No unclosed directives.
- Angularjs is loading once.

But no luck!

**Code Sample**

State Declaration

```js
.state('konsol.store.type.order.detail', {
        url: '/:orderCode/detail',
        views: {
          'navbar@': {
            template: require('./views/store-navbar.view.html'),
            controller: 'StoreNavbarController as vm'
          },
          'main@': {
            template: require('./views/order-management/order.view.html'),
            controller: 'StoreOrderController as vm'
          }
        },
        resolve: {
          currentState: function () {
            return 'konsol.store.type.order';
          },
          storeId: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.storeId;
          }],
          orderCode: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.orderCode;
          }],
          Orders: ['$stateParams', 'SomeService' function ($stateParams, SomeService) {
            return SomeService.getOrders($stateParams.storeId)
            // Here I make an http request to some API. This is Important for the last part of the question
          }],
          // Some other stuff ...
        }
      })
```

Controller

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('ic.konsol')
    .controller('StoreOrderController', StoreOrderController);

  // some injections they work fine
  StoreOrderController.$inject = ['$mdDialog','$window','$timeout','$rootScope','$stateParams','StoreOrderService','ShippingService','orders','store','businessPartnershipContract','shippingCompanies'];

  function StoreOrderController($mdDialog,$window,$timeout,$rootScope,$stateParams,StoreOrderService,ShippingService,orders,store,businessPartnershipContract,shippingCompanies
  ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.someText = 'Simple Text';
    alert();
  }
})();
```

View

```html
<h1>{{ vm.someText }}</h1>
```

**Output:**

The program works fine with no errors. It prints **Simple Text** But runs the `alert()` inside the controller twice

**One Last Important Detail**

Inside the state resolve I make an http request to some API. On my browsers Developer Mode I looked at Network tab and observed that It sends only one request. Not two. So what I think what is happening is about the controller itself.

**The Question**

Can someone on the earth tell me why my controller runs twice?

Comment: are you initializing in in your html too? I see it declared in your configs but cannot see your html files.

Comment: did you call your controller in the view ? like this :`<div ng-controller="Shell as shell">`

Comment: @NejiSoltani Can you please read the full question? I already said that I didn't

Comment: @DragonKnight I am sure that there is no ng-app or ng-controller on my page

Comment: Change vm to vm1 and vm2 see if it works!

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are using the same alias for both the controllers StoreNavbarController and StoreOrderController, can you change that and try.

Comment: No it is not about that. I use the same strategy for other pages non of them actually run twice. But re-checked for you by changing one of them. No luck again!